# When i compile this programm it puts radon text in the console

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

When i compile and run it tons of random letters appear in it closes

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, int* argv[])
{


    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < argc; x++)
    {
    while(*argv[x])
        {
        putchar(*argv[x]);
        *argv[x]++;
        }
    putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This Programm should take the input from the comand line
and print it(i wanted it in this format to test why and how *argv[] works)

Comment: `while(*argv[x])` Not sure what you are trying to do there but `x` is not changed in that loop so it's always accessessing the same `argv[x]` continuously and of course it never ends.

Comment: ***This Programm should take the input from the console*** No, `argv` takes the values from command-line arguments not `stdin`. If you want to take inputs from `stdin` use `scanf`.

Comment: Check what you're looping over. The code does not match the prose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in the third line:

```
int main(int argc, int* argv[])
```

It should be `char *agrv[]`, not `int *argv[]`. Writing `int *argv[]` is wrong as `int` is of four bytes and `char` is of only one

Writing this instead should fix the issue:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider checking for errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Exit status if the argument count is incorrect
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./program string\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Also you may want to print the string without writing a loop using `printf()` fucntion.

```
// Print the whole string in one step
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```